# Implementing a hover info box

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have a calendar, and when the user hovers over a cell, a large-ish info box appears with details for that date.  I am having some trouble though making the info box disappear when the user moves away.

I basically want it so that when the mouse cursor moves out of the calendar cell which is hidden by the info box it will disappear.  But I'm having trouble with this because `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` get messed up by having the info box as the top element.

So I tried to get around this by using "placeholder" divs that are transparent, have the same shape and location as the calendar cell beneath it, and have a z-index of 1000 so they are above the info box.  I then apply the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to these divs instead.

There's two problems with this though.  One, I have now messed up my HTML semantically.  The divs have no purpose but to get around what seems to be a limitation.  And secondly, they mess up my jQuery UI selection (I've applied it to the calendar cells - a click no longer selects a cell).

Is there a clean way to handle displaying an info box?  There will be no user interaction with the info box -- it's just to display information.

**EDIT**: Here is some code:

```
<li>
    <div class="day-content">
    </div>
    <div class="day-content-placeholder">
    </div>
</li>
```

and CSS

```
li
    { position: absolute; width: 15%; height: 20%; top: ... left: ... }
.day-content
    { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.day-content-placeholder
    { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1000; }
.popup
    { position: absolute; width: 300%; height: 300%; left: -150%; top: -150%; z-index: 500; }
```

and Javascript

```
var popup;
$('.week-content-placeholder')
    .mouseenter(function()
        {
        popup = $('<div class="popup">'+a_lot_of_text+'</div>').insertAfter(this);
        })
    .mouseleave(function()
        {
        popup.remove();
        });
```

That's not the exact code, but you get the idea.  This works okay, but like I said, since `.week-content-placeholder` is above `.week-content`, the selection capability with jQuery UI doesn't work properly on `.week-content`.

Comment: It might be useful to know what the html of your calendar *is* to answer this question.

Comment: Well, it's not a very calendar specific question.  It's just a div that has a mouseenter event that appends another div next to it.  This div has a large width and height, but it now obscures the div below it, blocking its mouseleave event.

Comment: Nick,  Why don't you use CSS "position" to place your info box on the screen such that it doesn't fully obstruct the calendar cell?

Comment: Yes, I know. But it helps to see what elements you're working with to suggest useful, specific, not-just-a-plugin-gallery answers to your question.

Comment: That's really part of the design though.. The calendar has text in each cell that is too small, so the user moves there mouse over it, and a popup over the cell is big enough to hold the large amount of information.  If I move the popup to a different location, it could confuse the user as to what it corresponds to.

Comment: Okay, I'll add some of my code.  Give me a minute.

Comment: Don't want to screw your hard work and all, but have you checked plugins like [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html)? They have a working tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your solution with the transparent "placeholder" divs in the following way:

Have the "placeholder" dive underneath the "calendar cell", using `{zIndex: -1}`.

When you enter a calendar cell, unhide the large "content" div and set `{zIndex: 1000}` on the "placeholder" div to bring it to the top.

Have a "mouseout" event on the placeholder div that will hide the "content" div and set `{zIndex: -1}` for the the "placeholder" cell.

Rather than create the "placeholder" cells in the HTML, you could create one in the javascript and move it to the postion of each "calendar" cell as you "mouseIn" it. You could also duplicate any "click" events on the "calendar cell" onto this one as well.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks, that works great!  I have one question though.  Sometimes when I move my mouse quickly across the calendar it doesn't register the mouseout event for the placeholder div and multiple info boxes stay on the screen.  I have to go back and mouseover it, and then mouseout again for it to disappear.  But you answered my question -- thanks.

Comment: Maybe try bringing the "placeholder" up first and "fadeIn" the content say over a 1 second period to give a little bit more time to register the event. I prefer fadeIn anyway for things like this,; it's less jarring on the eye.

Comment: Sorry I realise my last comment was the opposite of what you asked. Try keeping the "placeholder" at {zIndex: 1000} and duplicating the calendar cell's "click" event to it.

Comment: Another way would be to use "timeOut" to delay showing the "content for a quarter of a second, which would tend to make the user slow down his mouse movement when traversing cells. The "mouseout" event could call clearEvent to inhibit showing the content if it had not already started.

Comment: One last comment. Look at the jQuery documentation on ".stop()" and ".delay()". I think that these will be useful for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to make the info box a child of the cell:

```
<div id='box'>
    Normal content
    <div id='inner'>
        This big box obscures everything in the cell!
    </div>
</div>
```

The inner box is hidden until the hover occurs. Notice how with CSS we can make the box bigger than the cell itself with negative margins.

```
#box
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:100px;
  border:solid 2px darkblue;
  position:relative;
}
#box #inner
{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#eeee00;
  top:-10px;
  left:-10px;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
}
```

And you can use normal jquery hover because the hover covers box the box and it's child:

```
$('#box').hover(function(){
    $('#inner').show();
},function(){
    $('#inner').hide();
});
```

Here's it running:

http://jsfiddle.net/RbqCT/

You can create the info box dynamically as you do in your code.

Comment: Very cool technique, and it keeps the "inner" information semantically associated within the box it applies to. When I tried the fiddle, though, it didn't hide `#inner` when my mouse left the confines of the `#box` rectangle - it didn't hide until I moused out of `#inner` - which leaves the same problem as my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for all the work!  But it doesn't quite fit what I am trying to do, which is to get #inner to disappear when the mouse is moved outside of #box.  With your example, I have to move the mouse outside of #inner for the hover-out function to occur (meaning if #inner is 500x500 then I have to move my mouse very far for hover-out to occur).  I do like the semantically correct way this is done, so that answers one part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's 15 different plugins that let you do this with jquery:

> http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/

Comment: Thanks.  I have searched for these sorts of plug-ins, but none of them fit exactly what I'm trying to do, which is to completely cover the item the cursor is over, while still responding to the mouseleave event for that item.  Unless I missed it, I don't believe one of those 15 works like this (they offset the tooltip).

Answer (score 1):

You could track mousemouse and use the offsetLeft + width and offsetTop + height  of your hover trigger against the event.pageX and event.pageY to compare.

Comment: This is more what I'm looking for!  How exactly would I track the mouse movement?

Answer (score 0):

If you make this work as you described a tiny mouse movement that remains within the calendar cell (which is not even visible) leaves the popup in place, but a slightly larger movement that exits the cell makes the popup disappear.

The user sees only movement within the popup itself — small movement within the popup leaves it in place; large movement makes it go away.

I suggest triggering the disappearance of the popup on exiting the popup div itself. Any movement that remains within the "tip" panel leaves it up.  I think that (1) this is better usability and (2) it avoids the whole problem with the obscured calendar cell event handling.

You could do that by adding a `.mouseleave()` handler to the div when you create it.

Comment: Your first paragraph describes exactly what I'm trying to do, and in fact I originally implemented it exactly as you have described.  However, the "tooltip" takes up so much room that it almost completely covers the calendar cells next to the one being hovered over, which means if a user wants to see the tooltip for the next cell, they have to go to the very edge of it (and sometimes it is covered completely).