# Jquery - drag and drop mask that doesn't hide page's events

Tags: jquery, html

I am building a small website.
In my website users can perform different operations, everything is written in plain html. Nothing complex there.

Now, here comes the trick. I'd like to give my users the ability to drag and drop images and place them in a mask on top pf the page they are viewing.

This doesn't work well since  the mask blocks all operations users used to be able to do. My old html controls no longer receive focus when the user click them, as my upper mask  catches all click events. Is there any way to get around this? Maybe somehow tell the script engine to set the z-index of the original page as the topmost, yet not hiding the mask?

Comment: Hi, You need to show us the relevant parts of the HTML and jquery code to really understand what you want to do and how to do it. Also, if you have the website available, why not post its URL, so we can see for ourselves in order to help?

Comment: @neil, I fear it is currentl under development (running locally on my computer). I will try to paint it. Hope that will explain things better.

Comment: Could you toggle the mask only for drag/drop action?

Comment: I need it to show all the time.

Comment: I answered a similar query a day or two ago. The solution could be to put on top of the mask (i.e. with {zIndex: 1000}) a transparent div for each element that has an event and duplicate the events to these transparent divs. See my suggestion at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797498/implementing-a-hover-info-box/4797845#4797845

Comment: @Neil, is there any other way to shoot up these events? it seems rather tedious and incredibly heavy to copy all my html.

Comment: I agree. it was easier for the other guy, as he had only 1 element to cater for. But I can't see how else to do it if you hide your clickable elements underneath another element (the mask), unless you go to the pain of finding where, in absolute position your clickable elements are, then finding the cursor's position on the click and trigger the relevant event.

Comment: One more point. There is a CSS property called "pointer-events" (see: http://css-tricks.com/pointer-events-current-nav/) that will do what you want, but only for certain browsers.It works in Firefox 3.6+, Safari 3+, and the latest Chrome versions (v5+?) but not in IE or Opera yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're putting a full width/height div with a higher Z-index than the original page. You then add images to that div element through drag drop?

[Implementing a hover info box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797498/implementing-a-hover-info-box/4797845#4797845)
has what you could use as Neil has already shown.

Another option would be to find all controls at the Specific X, Y click - even those hidden by divs.
[Given an x,y coordinate, I need to find all html elements underneath it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280660/given-an-x-y-coordinate-i-need-to-find-all-html-elements-underneath-it)

Comment: Interesting approach. Didn't think of it this way. will give it a try